# How to add and remove text field on click of a button in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have generated button using ng-repeat directive in angular js. Now I want to generate a textfield inside a *div* tag on click of that button.

Example buttons -

[image]

Example textfields added on click of it -

[image]

I am doing this using innerHTML attribute of *div* tag, like below -

```
var txt = document.getElementById("paidby").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("paidby").innerHTML=txt+ "<div class='row' style='padding:2px'><div class='col-sm-4'><input type='number' placeholder="+str+"></div></div>";
```

But I want to know if there is any other better way using angularJS or javascript to do the same so that if I need to remove one or all of the textfields later on, it can be done easily. By removing means deleting and NOT hiding.

(becuase if I want to remove for example textfield 'two' now, I have no idea how I remove it)

Comment: Create the input element and use its id as a reference when deleting.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that you are not understanding the use case for Angular. See if this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/968155) makes sense to you before you proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to manipulate the DOM within your controller. Often times, there are better ways to do this within the framework that Angular provides.

You can do this by having another ng-repeat which loops over an array you declare within your controller. For example:

In your view:

```
<section id="paidby" ng-repeat="textfield in textfields">
  <div class='row' style='padding:2px'>
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
      <input type='number' placeholder="{{textField.str}}" ng-model="textField.value">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

In your controller, within your button ng-click logic:

```
// To add:
$scope.textFields.push({ str: someVariable, value: someValue });

// To remove:
var index = $scope.textFields.map(function(t) { return t.value; }).indexOf(someValue);
if (index !== -1) {
  $scope.textFields.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try hiding the inputs to start with, then show them if the appropriate button is clicked:

```html
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="array=['one','two','three','four','five']; show=[false,false,false,false,false]">

<button ng-repeat="item in array" ng-click="show[$index] = !show[$index]">{{item}}</button>
<br>
<input type="text" ng-repeat="item in array" placeholder="{{item}}" ng-if="show[$index]" />

</div>
```